# Include ExtJS control into my div

Tags: extjs

I am trying to use [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/portal/portal.html) to include this im my web-site. The matter is, if I try to copy it into my application, these controls fit all page. How can I include ExtJS controls into my div?

Comment: I think you should look at the ViewPort control. I think you problem is that the ViewPort extends to the entire browser window. Is this what you are looking for? Try posting a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: Yea, thanks. I've changed base control to `Ext.panel.Panel`, set `renderTo` property and everything works. Post this as answer and I'll mark it as "correct"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `renderTo` propery to specify id of element, where control should be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The ExtJS Portal demo uses an `Ext.Viewport` control to maximize the application to the entire browser window. To have the portal or parts inside another element or control, exchange the Viewport control with a `Ext.Container` or a `Ext.Panel`.